# Easy completion for internal links to figures/images?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I am writing a manuscript and I want to be able to reference my figures in the manuscript which I have included like the manual suggests:

```
#+CAPTION: Figure caption
#+NAME:   fig:my-figure
     [[./figures/my_figure.pdf]]
```

I basically want to pop up a helm search and autocomplete elsewhere in the document to find the figure I want and reference it. Can this be achieved using `C-c C-l` `org-insert-link` or is something new needed? This only brings up a canned list of tags.

I have seen [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27647/autocompletion-when-creating-internal-links-in-org-mode) but the question is asking only for headers.

Comment: Have you seen [org-ref](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref)?

Comment: I actually have it installed and it is able to recognize the figure names but when I insert the link it puts in `ref:fig:my-figure`. I use org-ref for some things but it is way too complicated and has too much functionality, I feel like there is an easier solution.