# Use counsel/ivy to insert org-links?

Tags: org-mode, counsel

I'm trying to use counsel/ivy to insert org links, but I haven't found a way to do this. I just want something to replace `org-insert-link` with a counsel interface. Can anyone help?

Comment: With counsel/ivy, you can select/choose from predefined candidates. Though, `org-insert-link` requires input every time. What/how do you want to choose?

Comment: If you have ivy (ivy-mode) enabled, then org-insert-link uses an ivy interface to do it. What do you want that is different that that?

Comment: This answer I gave a while ago may be helpful. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48551/how-to-auto-complete-links-to-headlines-in-org-mode/48556#48556