# list internal org-mode links

Tags: org-mode, org-link

How can I see a list of internal links in an org-mode document?  I would like a quick way to link within my document without needing to retype/remember all my internal links.

The [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html#DOCF29) states,

> To insert a link targeting a headline, in-buffer completion can be used. Just type a star followed by a few optional letters into the buffer and **press M-TAB**. All headlines in the current buffer will be offered as completions.

The key binding `M-TAB`, however, toggles the desktop environment's "switch to open application" functionality:

```
* Header1 <<h1>>
** Subheader1
   This is where I would like to reference *
```

[image]

Reading the documentation for [handling links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html), I have tried placing my cursor on the `<<h>>` target and manually calling `org-store-link`.  Emacs processes for a moment.  However, I am unable to use `TAB` for completion, in the buffer or minibuffer, and the stored target is not in the history accessed by `M-p/M-n`:

> *C-c C-l     (org-insert-link)*
>
> ...
>
> Inserting stored links
>
> All links stored during the current session are part of the history for this prompt, so you can access them with UP and DOWN (or
>   M-p/n).

Answer (score 1):

The manual suggests using Esc-Tab when M-Tab is captured by the desktop environment.

I tried this but found the completion to be underwhelming.  Here is what I did instead:
(making use of Ivy and some extra code)

[How to auto-complete links to headlines in org-mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48551/how-to-auto-complete-links-to-headlines-in-org-mode/48556#48556)

Comment: Ah yes, didn't even consider Esc, as I'm an evil-mode (Vim) user.  I'm glad you mention it though.  I also appreciate the pointer to the Pragmatic Emacs solution.  That gives me a path to go down when I have time to trial/research things.  Cheers!